# How to remove XCTest modules from Single View Application template?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, xctest

I have a *small* C# application that I am porting (essentially re-writing) for iOS using a Single View Application to build and test with.  It's so small that I don't need XCTest (nor do I want to pay for the Server code).  I have written the code for the base routines and now I just want to write a small test class to test the functionality of the base routines.

How do I remove the XCTest stuff and indicate to Xcode 5 that the test class is where to start the run, and not the base routines?  A reference to a doc or article would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you speaking about? What modules? What base routines?

Comment: The ones I am writing... consisting of "base routines" and a test program to test them with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's so small that I don't need XCTest

Use XCTest. It's a small framework, it's standard and it's better than any "small" testing framework you want to write and use instead. Why writing your own framework when you can use the standard one?

> nor do I want to pay for the Server code

There is no need to pay for XCTest. It can be run from any build server easily.

> small test class to test the functionality of the base routines

Create a XCTest

> How do I remove the XCTest stuff and indicate to Xcode 5 that the test class is where to start the run, and not the base routines?

Well, XCTest can be removed just by removing the unit test target. To start your own tests, you would have to create another target and do everything you want in it's `main` function.
Nothing complicated but why do it?

Comment: good answer... the only reason I can think of using it after reading your answer is to learn how to do it (which never hurts).  However, I have been looking at KIF... have you used it?  Do I need to remove XCTest to use KIF?  (the reason I was going to look at/use KIF is I have a very large iOS app that could really benefit from KIF).  Would be interested in what you have to say... :D